# jQuery Animate Height on Hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Why doesn't this work?

```
$("#left").hover(
    function () {
        $("#left .more").animate({height:"120px"}, 500);
    }
);
```

I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: We'll need to see your HTML as well to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild shot in the dark because you haven't shown any HTML.

Wait for `document.ready` before binding events because the DOM tree hasn't loaded when the JS gets executed:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  //code goes here
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could bind your events using `live` or `delegate` so that they're correctly executed even after additional DOM elements are inserted:

```
$('#left').live('hover', function...);
```

Comment: That was it, just didn't think I had to use that if it wasn't something that happened onload. Thanks. I'll accept in 8 minutes when I can.

Comment: @Rev, I'll add another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me... Try to work it out from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8YZtz/1/).

I assume you made a selecting mistake (#left .more)

Comment: strange that ti t worked for you, the code is correct, but adding document.ready made it work for me.

Comment: Yeah, because jsfiddle automatically takes care of JS/jQuery loading.